# Box behind another in CSS

Tags: html, css

I don't want the large box to move when the buttons at the top move. The box will contain text, but on the hover of the buttons, the box moves. Any way to fix this? Code I use below:

```
    <html>
<title>Website</title>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            background: url(bg.png);
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
        }


        .button {
            float: left;
            top: 100px;
            text-decoration:none;
            text-align:center; 
            color: #000000;
            text-shadow: 0 2px 2px #333333;
            font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
            border-radius: 8px;
            padding:35px 32px;
            background: url("pic.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
        }
        .button:hover {
            float: left;
            top: 100px;
            text-decoration:none;
            text-align:center; 
            padding:68px 32px;
            font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
            border:none; 
            display: block;

        }
        .b-pos {
            margin-top:50px;
            margin-left:34%;
            }


        .box {
            float: left;
            top: 100px;
            text-decoration:none;
            text-align:center; 
            color: #000000;
            text-shadow: 0 2px 2px #333333;
            font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
            border-radius: 8px;
            margin-left: 80px;
            margin-top: 190px;
            width: 1000px;
            height: 500px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
            box-shadow: 0 8px 8px -6px black, 0 -8px 8px -6px black, -8px 0 8px -6px black, inset 0px 0px 10px 0px #000000;
        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="b-pos">
        <a href="#" class="button" style="box-shadow: 0 8px 8px -6px black, 0 -8px 8px -6px black, -8px 0 8px -6px black, inset 0px 0px 10px 0px #000000;">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="button" style="box-shadow: 0 8px 8px -6px black, 0 -8px 8px -6px black, inset 0px 0px 10px 0px #000000;">Sales</a>
        <a href="#" class="button" style="box-shadow: 0 8px 8px -6px black, 0 -8px 8px -6px black, 8px 0 8px -6px black, inset 0px 0px 10px 0px #000000;">About</a>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

All the code that is needed is above. I don't think the background is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take either the buttons or the box out of the normal flow of HTML. You can do this by setting the CSS `position` attribute of, for example `.box` to `absolute` or `fixed`.

```
.box {
  position: absolute;
 }
```

This will "lock" the box in place.

Answer (score 1):

Just add: `position:fixed;`
in the box css and it will not move.

The `fixed attribute` means that the element is positioned relative to the browser window. Hence it will stay where it is irrespective of the above movement when the button is hovered upon.

Also you can use `position:absolute` here. Absolute means the element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element.